# Django TIME_ZONE is set but correct default is not set for datetime field

Tags: django, datetime, nginx, django-rest-framework, timezone

I set `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'` into project settings also I have datetime field into my models like below:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

But the correct default value is not set for datetime field.

I did the same thing before and it was correct, maybe it could be from nginx?

Code is running into Linux (Ubuntu) server.

Comment: What do you mean "not correct"? Is the time zone off? Django saves datetime as UTC in database and makes the conversion in application level.

Comment: if are you using db.sqlite3 then its work properly,
but if are you use postgres or mongo like database then you should be overide timezone on your database

Comment: @suayipuzulmez please pay attention to `default=timezone.now`

Answer (score 0):

if are you using db.sqlite3 then its work properly,
but if are you use postgres or mongo like database then you should be overide timezone on your database

Comment: yeah, i use mysql datebase, how to override?